# If we have an infinite intersection $\bigcap_{\text{distinct } a,b,c \in X} (M_a \cup M_b \cup M_c)$, then how can we compute that as a union?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, closed-form

Let $X$ be an infinite set and let $(M_i)_{i\in X}$ be a family of sets indexed by $X$.  Suppose $\bigcap_{i\geq 1} M_{a_i} = \{1\}$ whenever the sequence $a_i \in X$ contains infinitely many distinct entries.

Consider the intersection:

$$
\bigcap_{\text{distinct } a,b,c \in X} (M_a \cup M_b \cup M_c) 
\tag{1}
$$

Can we write this expansion as an infinite union of finite intersections of the $M_i$?  What is the most succinct form you can think of to write it out as a union?

I'm tripping up because of the fact that there are three unioned terms and so I'm not sure what form the final union will take.

---

**Attempt.**  The intersection seen in (1) above is equal to:

$$
\bigcap_{a \in X} \bigcap_{b \in X \\ b \neq a} \bigcap_{c \in X \\ c \neq a,b} (M_a \cup M_b\cup M_c) = \bigcap_{a \in X} \left(M_a\cup \bigcap_{b \in X \\ b \neq a} \left ( M_b \cup \bigcap_{c \in X \\ c \neq a,b} M_c\right)\right) \tag {2}
$$

I'm thinking the intersection (1) is trivially $= \{1\}$. Do you get the same result?

Comment: Thanks @EricWofsey you've saved the post.  This is definitely regarding another problem, that I need not mention and will not because it incurs automatic downvoting, which isn't fair if you ask me.  It's as if saying a realm of math problems is off-topic for the site.

Comment: I've edited to remove some more irrelevant details and clarify the presentation.

Comment: @EricWofsey thank you.  Seeing as I can write it in the last form at the bottom.  It looks (since $X$ is infinite) and we assume that $\bigcap_{i\geq 1} M_{a_i} = \{1\}$ that the whole thing collapses to $\{1\}$ the element contained in every $M_{j}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed compute the intersection by following your attempt and observing that the innermost big intersection is just $\{1\}$, and consequently so are each of the outer intersections in turn.  There is a more intuitive way to think about it, though.

Let $S$ denote your intersection.  Instead of thinking about $S$, let's think about its complement.  When is $x\not\in S$?  Well, that just means there exist distinct $a,b,c\in X$ such that $x$ is not in any of $M_a,M_b,$ or $M_c$.  In other words, this means there are at least three different $i\in X$ such that $x\not\in M_i$.  So, negating this, $x\in S$ just means that $x$ is in all but at most two of the $M_i$.  If you like, you can write this as $$S=\bigcup_{i,j\in X}\bigcap_{k\neq i,j}M_k.$$  Here for each fixed $i,j\in X$, the inner intersection consists of all the elements that are in every $M_k$ except possibly $M_i$ and $M_j$.

In your case, since you know any intersection of infinitely many of the $M_i$ is just $\{1\}$, all of these inner intersections will be $\{1\}$, and so $S$ will be $\{1\}$.